# Crafting an interpreter, how do i create a vector of token objects of different types in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, interpreter

So I am going through the book "Crafting an Interpreter" and opted to implement the interpreter in C++ instead of Java like in the textbook. I am creating the Token type right now and it needs to store literals of different types. For example, a token with type TokenType::String will contain a string literal and a token with type TokenType::Number will contain a integer literal. The author of the book uses Java's Object type to accomplish this but this does not exist in C++.

A potential solution I have come to is to use templates: Token< type >, but I cannot put these in the same vector if using multiple literal types. So I have attempted to abstract the token into an "interface" class called IToken and create a vector of type Vector< IToken > to resolve this, but I don't think you can make the abstract class ungeneric while making the concrete generic. What would be the best way to implement what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Inheritance and polymorphism? That's usually what I use when creating parsers.

Comment: if your parser won't be extended at runtime you might want to use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which is slightly faster than normal polymorphism, but can't be extended at runtime.

Comment: I usually have a base class `Token`.  I then have intermediary class like `Instruction` and `Operator`.  You can build from the bottom up by looking at all the token classes and propagating common methods and members to a parent class.  Repeat until you get to a single parent.

Comment: In C++, polymorphism is done by using pointers or references.  In Java, everything is a pointer (in C++ terminology).

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to look at ANTLR4. It can be really cool and can help you with your tokenizer. But that's not what you're asking.

```
class BaseToken {
public:
    using Vector = std::vector<BaseToken *>;
...
};
class FooToken: public BaseToken {...};
class BarToken: public BaseToken {...};

BaseToken::Vector allTokens;
```

Read about C++ polymorphism for more info.